# Jquery: Add fieldset element between form

Tags: jquery, forms, fieldset

How to insert fieldset inform using jquery now I have this

```
<form action="" method="post">

all dynamic field generated with db and array

</form>
```

I want to add fieldset between form tag so code become

```
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset>

all dynamic field generated with db and array

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: In which server side language you are fetching the data from db ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend doing this server-side, but if you really need to use jQuery for this:

```
$('form').wrapInner('<fieldset />');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jjmcn/2/)

[`.wrapInner` docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

Comment: Wonderful.. short and sweet.. thanks and will be selected once restricted time over ( 9 minutes ).. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

or you can do it like this:

```
    var newForm = "<fieldset>"+$('form').html()+"</fieldset>";
    $('form').html(newForm);
```

Comment: This also works but I prefer short code. Just for knowledge does it more future proof than Fabricio Matte's code?

Comment: the major problem with `.html()` is that it overwrites all existing elements, effectively causing a complete re-parsing of the form elements and trashing out all previously attached listeners.

Comment: @pixelngrain You should accept Fabrício Matté answer. It's much better than my answer. my answer just another way.

Comment: Yes, this falls in the "it works" category, but in the longer run you may run into issues. Yet another solution is to detach the form's children, append the children to a newly created fieldset element and append this fieldset to the form - but well, that is basically what the `wrapInner` method does behind the scenes so there's no need to do that manually.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M appreciate your effort and fair opinion. Thanks once agian for help

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Nice explain. Thanks to give me some knowledge regarding what's going behind the scene and how this code works. Appreciated.